# Asynchronous call with RxJava -Observables

Tags: java, rest, asynchronous, rx-java

I'm trying to make asynchronous rest calls by implementing RxJava.
Below is the implementation -

```
final Observable<List<A>> observableA = Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<List<A>>() {
    @Override
    public void call(Subscriber<? super List<A>> subscriber) {
        try {
            if (!subscriber.isUnsubscribed()) {
                subscriber.onNext(//another Function call);
                subscriber.onCompleted();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            subscriber.onError(e);
        }
    }
});

final Observable<List<B>> observableB = Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<List<B>>() {
    @Override
    public void call(Subscriber<? super List<B>> subscriber) {
        try {
            if (!subscriber.isUnsubscribed()) {
                subscriber.onNext(//another Function call);
                subscriber.onCompleted();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            subscriber.onError(e);
        }
    }
});


Observable<List<C>> reservationObserv = Observable.zip(observableA, observableB, new Func2< List<A>, List<B> ,  List<C>>() {
    @Override
    public List<C> call(final List<A> a, final List<B> b) {
        // Merge the response
        return c;
    }
});
```

As of now, ObservableA is first executed and then ObservableB. 
Can any one please suggest why the calls are not asynchronous.

Thanks in advance.

when I execute in the following way, observableB is executed first and then ObservableA

```
final Observable<List<A>> observableA = Observable.create(new  Observable.OnSubscribe<List<A>>() {

@Override
public void call(final Subscriber<? super List<A>> subscriber) {
    Runnable run = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // Delay of 1000ms
            subscriber.onNext(//calling a method);
            subscriber.onCompleted();
        }
    };
    executorService.execute(run);
}
});

final Observable<List<B>> observableB = Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<List<B>>() {

@Override
public void call(final Subscriber<? super List<B>> subscriber) {
    Runnable run = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // No delay
            subscriber.onNext(//calling a method);
            subscriber.onCompleted();
        }
    };
    executorService.execute(run);
}
});


Observable<List<C>> observableC = Observable.zip(observableA, observableB, new Func2< List<A>, List<B> ,  List<C>>() {
@Override
public List<C> call(final List<A> a, final List<B> b) {
    // Merge the response
    return c;
}
});
```

Comment: When you say "ObservableA is first executed and then ObservableB," what do you mean by that?  What starts the whole process off?

Comment: Thanks @Robert Harvey for formatting the code. As RxJava helps to execute in parallel way and zip the response at the end, I tried to implement in the same manner. But here, the calls are being made in synchronous way. Am i missing something?

Comment: Look at Schedulers. By default RxJava is single-threaded.

Answer (score 2):

By default, RxJava is synchronous. So in your first case, the zip operator will subscribe to `observableA`, then, when `observableA` will complete, will subscribe to `observableB`.

In the second case, as you're using an executor service, you're defacto asynchronous.

To be async with your first version, as it's sugested in comments, you should look at `Schedulers` and tell to RxJava in which schdeulers your subscription should be perform.

```
Observable<List<C>> observableC = Observable.zip(
                   observableA.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()),
                   observableB.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()),
                   (a, b) -> /** ... **/);
observableC.subscribe();
```

You can use different schedulers, depending on what you want to achive. (using Schedulers.io() for I/O, ...)